# How to get lowest price from product collection?

Tags: magento2

Is their any way we can get the lowest price from product collection ?

I have array of products id

```
Array
(
    [0] => 662348
    [1] => 659160
)
```

I want the minimum & maximum price of products.
min price product & max price product.

I have tried

```
$proIds=array(2,6,7);
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productCollection */
    $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
    /** Apply filters here */
    $collection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $proIds));

                echo '<pre>';print_r($collection->getData());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass all the prices into empty array and then apply this function.

`max(); min();`

Answer (score 0):

You can get **min** and **max** price from any collection :

**Max Price :** `$maxPrice = $productCollection->getMaxPrice();`

**Min Price :** `$minPrice = $productCollection->getMinPrice();`